# How to check how old is a site?

Tags: website

If there an official website or something to check the age of a site.

Answer (score 14):

You could put the website URL into [The Internet Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/collections/web.html) and see how far back the archives go. Note that it only goes back to 1996 however, but this should be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: +1 That is outstanding! If you could get more than one, you'd get it!

Comment: Thanks. And yeah, the Internet Wayback Machine is a great tool - better than Google's cache in many cases. :)

Comment: Actually, the Wayback Machine is pretty incomplete, both in site coverage as well as in providing the exact point in time a site was created. It uses the IACrawler, which only finds sites that are linked from a third site, and can be blocked via the robots.txt. Expect the results to differ 0-24 months from the actual date. Additionally, lack of availability of a site in the Internet Wayback Machine is not proof of non-existance.

Comment: It's a good tool for larger sites, doesn't work that precisely good for smaller ones. It's probably one of the best solutions though.

Comment: Is it a crawler?

Comment: @Martin: I've found the Wayback machine to be a lot more complete than you have, it seems. Of course, it's not perfect, especially for smaller sites, but it does a darn good job.

Comment: Knowing about the Wayback machine has saved my bacon on more than on occassion and made me look like a total wizard on several more.  Whilst many people will have heard of the Google cache the wayback machine is much more obscure

Answer (score 7):

You can check the [Domain Whois](http://whois.domaintools.com/idea.hu) to see when the domain was registered.

Comment: Domains are often registered long before the website goes up, however.

Comment: Yes, this method should probably be used together with the Internet Wayback machine or some other way to determine when there was content on the domain.

Comment: @Gergely: Yeah, exactly. In combination they should tell you a good answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can check alexa.com .. it can provide some info..

Answer (score 0):

You could check [www.netcraft.com](http://www.netcraft.com) they have lots of server uptime information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of Websites that show you a lot of information of websites such as [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com) or [Website Figures](http://www.websitefigures.com).